# Firebase : How to force retrieval of new data for one particular node.

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, persistence

I had enabled `setPersistenceEnabled(true)`, then something happened by mistake and a node which is suppose to have children now doesn't;

The Node was in the form :

```
 Nodes : {
         concernedNode : {
                       child : "data",
                       child2 : "data"
         } 
   }
```

After an arror, the **concernedNode** changed to :

```
concernedNode : true
```

And in java, I get this data as follows :

```
concernedNodePojo pojo = dataSnapshot.getValue(concernedNodePojo.class);
```

As you can see, if concernedNode is now a boolean, this throws an exception where **concernedNodePojo** can't be converted to Boolean.

Now the problem is this is already in cache, if `setPersistenceEnabled(false)`, everything will work fine, but then if `setPersistenceEnabled(true)`, the App crushes because there's no way to delete the offline data.

I tried `setPersistenceEnabled(false)`, then retrieving new data so that the offline data can be written over, but that's not the case. Offline data gets checked and the app crushes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to manually delete the app data or reinstall the app.

Programmatically your best bet is to keep persistence enabled and retrieving the data without parsing it into your POJO. Just attach a listener that does nothing in its `onDataChange()` or, if you're curious to see if it has the new data, parses the snapshot without converting it to `concernedNodePojo`.

For example:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    System.out.println("Got "+snapshot.getKey());
    System.out.println("Got "+snapshot.child("child").getValue());
}
```

Comment: I'll actually have to write a custom code block like the one you posted as I was using the FirebaseListAdapter, but had used the custom code as example on this question.